# reading file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file containing the following text :

```
  8.8   0.0   0.00015      0.43      10      51       10      44        2      55  0.79
  10.9   0.0   3.5e-05       0.1     214     247       57      95       40     111  0.74
  10.5   0.0   4.7e-05      0.14     316     361      113     160      104     161  0.90
 -1.9   0.0      0.27     8e+02      62     109      385     432      372     465  0.76
```

As you can see, the number of space characters between each two adjacent numbers may vary.

I want to process each line , and save each number in a variable.

How can this be possible ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read each line and use `split("\\s+")` to break into 'words' or numbers.

Another approach is to use a Scanner which can handle multiple spaces as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `BufferedReader`, and its `readLine()`. Then use `split("\\s+")` and parse each element of the resultant array